# Problema con v-model

Tags: vue.js, web, template

El asunto es el siguiente, estoy tratando de hacer una vista previa de un cuestionario, entonces lo que hago es traer la información y darle el formato que el mismo usuario eligio cuando creo la encuesta, los datos se traen con relaciones y todo bien hay, el problema surge cuando marco opciones de la encuesta, que para traer la informacion lo hago en un v-for, la información varia, pero el v-model no, entonces quisiera como darle un v-model distinto a cada pregunta, un ejemplo de lo que esta pasando el codigo seria este:

```
<h1 class="page-title">Vista previa</h1>
    <el-col :xs="24" :md="24">
        <el-card>
            <div slot="header">
                <h1 class="page-title">{{survey.name}}</h1>
                    <span>
                        {{survey.description}}
                    </span>
             </div>
             <div v-for="item in survey.survey_questions">
                 <h2 class="mt-1 title-question">{{item.question}} 
                     <span class="optional" v-if="item.optional===1"></span>
                 </h2>
                 <div v-if="item.response_type_id===1">
                     <el-input type="textarea" v-model="textarea" class="mb-2" prop="text-area">
                     </el-input>
                 </div>
                 <div v-if="item.response_type_id===2">
                     <el-checkbox-group v-model="checked" :min="0" :max="1">
                         <div v-for="option in item.survey_question_option" prop="option">                                                                          
                             <el-checkbox :label="option.id">
                                 {{option.option}}
                             </el-checkbox>
                          </div>
                     </el-checkbox-group>
                 </div>
                 <div v-if="item.response_type_id===3">
                     <el-rate :texts="texts(item.rank)"
                               v-model="ranks"
                               :max="item.rank"
                               :show-text="show(item.show_text)"
                               allow-half>
                      </el-rate>
                 </div>
                 <div v-if="item.response_type_id===4">
                     <el-radio-group v-model="yesno">
                         <el-radio label="Si"></el-radio>
                         <el-radio label="No"></el-radio>
                      </el-radio-group>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </el-card>
     </el-col>
```

Para resumir mi problema es que, cuando se le da clic a una pregunta, se seleccion todas las de su mismo tipo y eso es porque el v-model es el mismo, yo quisiera saber una forma para que esto no pasara o como podria tener un v-model para cada pregunta

Answer (score 1):

La manera de conseguir un v-model propio en un array de objetos, es añadiendo una propiedad que contenga el valor, como ya te respondieron.

Pero hay que tener en cuenta de que Vue 2 (Dicen que estara corregido para la version 3) no se entera de los cambios cuando se añade una propiedad nueva a un objeto, lo cual no se vuelve reactiva la misma. Para evitar esto, hay que forzar a Vue a que vuelva a recorrer el objeto, esto se puede hacer de varias maneras:

```
this.survey.survey_questions = this.survey.survey_questions.map(item => {

    item.answer = ''

    return item

})
```

```
this.survey.survey_questions.forEach(item => {

    item.answer = ''

})

this.survey.survey_questions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.survey.survey_questions))
```

Otra manera de evitar esto, es hacer el recorrido asignando el valor vacio a los objetos antes de asignarlo a un data.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar agregar una propiedad a los elementos de `survey.survey_questions` como la siguiente forma

```
this.survey.survey_questions.map((item) => {
    item.answer = ''; //Cadena vacía
    return item;
});
```

Luego, dentro del v-for, el v-model de cada uno será `item.answer`

```
<div v-for="item in survey.survey_questions">
                 <h2 class="mt-1 title-question">{{item.question}} 
                     <span class="optional" v-if="item.optional===1"></span>
                 </h2>
                 <div v-if="item.response_type_id===1">
                     <el-input type="textarea" v-model="item.answer" class="mb-2" prop="text-area">
                     </el-input>
                 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hice algo parecido pero con algunas modificaciones el problema es que al darle clic, a escribir o ponerle un rate, los valores siguen en blanco o nulos, no se porque